# Change Stepper width / height from storyboard Xcode

Tags: uistepper, stepper

Is there a way we can change the stepper width / height from storyboard?  Must I do it through the programmatic approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to change the size in Xcode 11.x. If you want to manipulate the size you need to implement it programmatically, e.g. by transformation:

```
        stepper.transform = stepper.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.25, y: 0.9)
```